# Simple ng-repeat not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have following code in my angularjs app, why this simple ng-repeat is not working?

```js
var app = angular.module('anApp', []);
app.controller('aCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = ["", "File", "", "Edit", "", "Format", ""];
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="anApp" ng-controller="aCtrl">
  {{data}}
  <ol>
    <li ng-repet="j in data">{{j}}</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: use track by $index

Comment: The answers below are helpful, but could it just have been ng-repeat was misspelled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this. `data` array have duplicate item then use `track by $index`

```
<ol>
  <li ng-repeat="j in data track by $index">{{j}}</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: You misspelled `ng-repeat`

Comment: This is Working. you'll have to wait for few minutes to mark answer

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate keys are not allowed in AngularJS and also you misspelled `ng-repeat`

***[Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=j%20in%20data&p1=string:&p2=)***

```js
var app = angular.module('anApp', []);
app.controller('aCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = ["", "File", "", "Edit", "", "Format", ""];
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="anApp" ng-controller="aCtrl">
  {{data}}
  <ol>
    <li ng-repeat="j in data track by $index">{{j}}</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

[**Angular Doc.**](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes) Duplicate Key in Repeater

```js
var app = angular.module('anApp', []);
app.controller('aCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = ["", "File", "", "Edit", "", "Format", ""];
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="anApp" ng-controller="aCtrl">
  {{data}}
  <ol>
<li ng-repeat="j in data track by $index">{{j}}</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use this code it is working
In view
    {{data}}
      <ol>
      <li ng-repeat="j in data track by $index">{{j}}</li>
      </ol>

and in Javascript

var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.data = ["", "File", "", "Edit", "", "Format", ""];
});
```

and for you i am writting in plunker and please correct the spelling of ng-repeat

https://plnkr.co/edit/Q1OeiIzGBgpppluvtOT1?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for reply, <li ng-repeat="j in data track by $index">{{j}}</li> this will work then.I update the plunkr also